# Setting a bitwise column with jooq in mysql

Tags: jooq

I'm trying to do a bitwise operation while setting a column using JOOQ and MySQL. The statement I'm trying to convert to JOOQ is:

```sql
UPDATE users SET permission = permission | 16;
```

Is there a way todo this in JOOQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DSL.bitOr()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#bitOr(org.jooq.Field,T))

```java
ctx.update(USERS)
   .set(USERS.PERMISSION, bitOr(USERS.PERMISSION, 16))
   .execute();
```